# How should I "commit" my sqlalchemy statements?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

My question is at the bottom, but please read the background first.

Background:

I am writing python code that digests my teammate's raw sql code and submits it via sqlalchemy as-is, e.g.:

```
db=create_engine(sqlstr1) //make the connection just once
sqlstr1="select top 5 * from some_table" //keep refreshing this string with
               //successive excerpts from a .sql file ..
db_con.execute(sqlstr1) //and submit them.
```

...so just imagine that that whole .sql file is stepped-through in this way.

To anticipate a reaction: why do it like this?  Because neither I nor my team have time to learn really SQLAlchemy; we're just trying to get our raw sql code automated.  I imagine I'm not alone in using sqlalchemy that way.

I noticed that a basic select statement will take effect immediately.  But anything like a drop/create table statement has to be followed by a "Commit" statement of it won't take effect.  So I'm just writing an db_con.execute("connect")  into my loop.

OK, so the QUESTION: is there any better way to commit these table statements?

Comment: Don't waste your time finagling SQLAlchemy into doing what you want.  Just use psycopg2 or the equivalent for your brand of SQL.  `sqlite3` is even built into the standard library.  SQLAlchemy is for people who need actual object-relational mapping, which you're clearly not using.

Comment: I agree with Kevin, but there are ways to use SQLAlchemy for just executing raw SQL (and generating it, if you are concerned with portability to other RDBMSs). If you anticipate using other features later, it's better to get SQLAlchemy set up now than try to recode later.

Comment: However the "philosophical" discussion (I basically agree with both comments above) what strikes me of your post is that you need a `commit` after a `drop/create table` statement. In the databases that I know (postgres, oracle) you don't need to commit after a `create table` even with `autocommit` disabled. And it makes sense: it is not usually the case that you create a table and depending the decisions of your code you must `rollback` that creation. What database are you using? How are you doing your commit, `db_con.commit()`? How are you creating your tables?

Comment: lrnzcig, we are on redshift.  SO I am using basically psycopg2 as Kevin suggested.  I don't know why a commit is required, I just found that it made my code work so I went with it.